# Heroku PostgreSQL GROUP_BY error in Rails app

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I've got a rails app that works fine in development (SQLite) but is throwing lots of errors when I've deployed it via Heroku, which uses PostgreSQL I gather.

the error message getting returned:

```
        ActionView::Template::Error (PGError: ERROR:  
column "practices.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function: 
SELECT "practices".* 
FROM "practices" WHERE ("practices".activity_id = 1) 
AND ("practices"."created_at" BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-01-31') 
GROUP BY DATE(created_at) ORDER BY created_at DESC):
```

this is being thrown when I call the following:

```
def month_days_not_practiced(date = Date.today)
   p = practices.where(:created_at => date.at_beginning_of_month..date.at_end_of_month).group("DATE(created_at)").to_a.count
   days_in_month(date.year, date.month) - p
end
```

I'd really like to keep the code clean so it works on both development and production DBs...can anyone shed some light?

I have tried this:

```
def month_days_not_practiced(date = Date.today)
   p = practices.where(:created_at => date.at_beginning_of_month..date.at_end_of_month).group("practices.id, DATE(created_at)").to_a.count
   days_in_month(date.year, date.month) - p
end
```

to no avail...

tia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to group by *all* the columns in the select list, so

```
.group("practices.id, practices.foo, practices.bar, ..., DATE(created_at)")
```

Your idea to group only by `id` is sound (assuming `id` is the primary key), but PostgreSQL will only support that in version 9.1.

Comment: I've been thoroughly confused by this. If I have to group by all the columns that I select, then it seems I'm not grouping by any of them? Using y our answer removes the error but now I am left with essentially `.all`. I am sure I'm missing something here but it has alluded me thus far.

Answer (score 5):

```
Practice.group(Practice.col_list)



def self.col_list
  Practice.column_names.collect {|c| "practices.#{c}"}.join(",")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Practice.joins(:foobar).group_all

def self.group_all
  group(group_all_columns)
end

def self.group_all_columns
  @group_all_columns ||= column_names.collect {|c| "#{table_name}.#{c}"}.join(",")
end
```